# When users login to a site - should I select by the username and password, or just by the username?

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication, indexing

I'm using PHP and mySQL in a site I design from scratch.

When a user logs in to the site, should I :

- make the query `WHERE username='username' AND password='password'`, in which case I need to index the username and password fields, and can return a "Bad login" if one of the details is incorrect

or

- Make the query `WHERE username='username'` only, in which case I need to index just the username field, but need to check that the passwords match in the server side code

?

---

**UPDATE:**
This question is about good practice. It is about whether the pros of adding an index on the password field so I can get a response from the DB only if both of the details are correct, outweighs the cons of the space and size this index will take.
I don't think the specific of my system (other than the programming language, and DB type) are relevant, and will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do the latter (the username is "the thing you're searching for", even if you do an explicit password verification at some stage), but it's impossible to come up with a tailored answer for you, without in-depth familiarity with your particular codebase.

**Edit**

You mention indexing; indexing *both* the username and password fields only makes sense when `username` is not unique.. and it should be. So it's a bit of a moot point.

Answer (score 0):

as long as you have username='username' first in your sql sentence, then i believe you won't get a performance penalty on the password field.

I do not know this for certain, but i know that in programming languages one won't evaluate other statements in an `AND` chain if the first statement returns false.

```
if(iAlwaysReturnFalse() && soIWontGetEvaluated()){
  System.out.println("I never get printed out :( ");
}
```

However, you can easily check this assumption. if you have a large enough database. just do some tests. see how

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '...' and password = '...'
```

performs against

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE password = '....' and username = '...'
```

and against

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '...'
```

Comment: SQL is not a programming language. And it's a bit more complex than basic short-circuiting for SQL queries.

Comment: @Tomalak its reasonable to think that databases would use some of the same principles as a programming language.

Comment: @netbrain: Not if you understand how fundamentally different they are.

Comment: @Tomalak by all means, please enlighten me.

Comment: @netbrain: Teaching you what a DBMS is is out of the scope of this comment thread, and indeed this website. Read a book!

Comment: since you won't share your knowledge, then i still find it hard to believe that databases would evaluate AND chains as you are insinuating that they do.

Comment: @netbrain: I'm sorry to hear that. Suffice it to say, if you were to run the conditionals on the _entirety_ of a candidate set (as would be the direct procedural analogy), then your queries would take forever. Instead, a _query plan_ is created that may or may not use indexes and various other optimisations. The resulting operation is actually quite far removed from what you originally literally wrote in your query. SQL is _not_ a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide many details, but in general, I go for the 2nd option.It will allow you to do things like flagging a user after N attempts to log in with an incorrect password.

Oh and of course, remember to store your passwords in hash form with a properly random salt, never in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer the latter for the following reasons:

- You might want to save (unsuccessful) login attempts to the database, for that you need the user record regardless of an (in)correct password.
- You should be hashing your passwords, and you might want to implement your hashing algorithm in only one place (eg. your PHP code). If your algorithm would change, at least you don't need to modify your code AND your SQL query. For example:

  class User {

  protected $username;
  protected $password_hash;
  protected $salt;

  protected function hashPassword($password) {
  return md5($this->salt.$password);
  }

  public function checkPassword($password) {
  return ($this->hashPassword($password) == $this->password_hash);
  }

}

Answer (score -1):

The first method is better as in second if the username matches then you will have to again make a query to check password